# How should I release this?

Tags: swift

The documentation specifies the number of `CGPoints` the `points` property of `CGPathElement` holds in function of the value of its `type` property, for instance, there are two points for `AddQuadCurveToPoint`, one point for `.AddLineToPoint`, and... nothing for `.CloseSubpath`.

The documentation states that, since it's an UnsafeMutablePointer, it is the responsibility of the programmer to release it, so, for the cases where there a two points, I call `pPointer.dealloc(2)`, for those with one point `pPointer.dalloc(1)` but how about those with no point at all ? Should I still call something or not ? I believe I shouldn't, but since I am not used to manual memory management, I might miss something.

By the way, `pPointer` is defined outside the switch body.

Comment: Where did you get the CGPathElement from?

Comment: @jtbandes Right now I am just building a function that takes this type, but it will probably come form a CGPath.

Comment: You are not responsible for deallocating path elements that CGPathApply passes to your applier function. It's just giving you a window into the path's internal storage.

Comment: Ok thank you, but what if, for any reason, I didn't got it from here ?

Comment: Also, although I might get it from it, I am still storing directly the pointers in the body of my function, like `let pPointer = cgPathElement.points`

Comment: If you allocate it, or if the documentation tells you that you own it, you are responsible for deallocating it.